# Prevent repeated period after acronym

Tags: acro

I use the [`acro`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) package for acronyms. In the following example, I define the acronym "i.i.d.", which ends with a period. If I use it at the end of a sentence, I get two periods.

How can I avoid this automatically?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{iid}{short=i.i.d.,long=independent and identically distributed}

\begin{document}
The random variables A and B are \ac{iid}.
Likewise, the random variables C and D are \ac{iid}.
\end{document}
```

Output

```
The random variables A and B are independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.).
Likewise, the random variables C and D are i.i.d..
```

The first sentence is fine. The problem is the two periods at the very end of the second sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `\acdot` is intended to manage

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{iid}{short=i.i.d\acdot,long=independent and identically distributed}

\begin{document}
The random variables A and B are \ac{iid}.
Likewise, the random variables C and D are \ac{iid}.
\end{document}
```

However, there is some likely unexpected behaviour in the first instance of `\ac{iid}` as the command is followed by a dot, but the `\acdot` in the full form appears within brackets, rather than directly before the full stop.
This is intentional, and the [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) documentation gives an example with `\acspace` where suppressing characters *within* an acronym on the basis of a trailing token may be desirable.

In this case though, a bracket replacing a full stop is less desirable.  There is no user interface to deactivate trailing characters in specific contexts only, but we can modify the `long-short` template (or whatever non-default template is being used) to avoid this and use `\acro_trailing_action_deactivate:n` to deactivate checks for the `dot` character when printing the first-style so that `\acdot` reliably expands to `.` in those instances.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewAcroTemplate{long-short}{%
\acroiffirstTF{%
  \acro_trailing_action_deactivate:n {dot}
  \acrowrite{long}%
  \acspace(%
    \acroifT{foreign}{\acrowrite{foreign}, }%
    \acrowrite{short}%
    \acroifT{alt}{ \acrotranslate{or} \acrowrite{alt}}%
    \acrogroupcite
  )%
  }%
  {\acrowrite{short}}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The effect of `\acro_trailing_action_deactivate:n` is local so `\acs{iid}.` continues to absorb the extra stop, while first use of `\ac{iid}` and any further uses of `\acf{iid}` will never suppress the stop in the bracketed short form.

Comment: This is more or less what I intended to write when I had found the time :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the final period with `\acdot`, per section 19 of the acro manual.  It looks like this also supports a few other pieces of punctuation as well.  For your example, it should look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{iid}{short=i.i.d\acdot,long=independent and identically distributed}

\begin{document}
The random variables A and B are \ac{iid}.
Likewise, the random variables C and D are \ac{iid}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `short=i.i.d\acdot` the period disappears in the first sentence.

Comment: Nice, thank you. I didn't know about `\acdot`. However, as @AndreyL. mentions, also the first sentence is affected...